# Multiple DropDownList but same action

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two DropDownList with OnSelectedIndexChanged="SelectedIndexChanged" but I need to know in the C# code withch one is the one I used.

How can I know that?

Answering the questions:
 I'm using Web Forms  and I'm trying to change some GridViews Source from a choseen option in a DDL but the web had the same DDL  (with different IDs) in several places and I can't delete them...

Comment: Look at the `sender` argument your handler is given.

Comment: Shall we assume you are using Windows Forms?

Comment: check my answer and tell me if something is not clear, also why you need that will be good to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general form for an event handler is:

```
OnSomeEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

`sender` is a reference to the object that is raising the event.

In your case, `sender` is a reference to the `DropDownList` whose selected index has changed. So you should use something like this:

```
private void SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList the_list_that_changed = (DropDownList)sender;

    int ids = the_list_that_changed.SelectedIndex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter `sender` represents the object raising the event. Hence the `Sender` reference to your `DropDownList` whose triggered the selected index changed.

```
 private void SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    if (((DropDownList)sender).ID == "firstDropDownID")
    {
        //To Do for first dropdown
    }
    else
    {
        //To Do for second dropdown
    }
 }
```